# Django request method defaults to GET while the tutorial I'm working with is using a POST in the code

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am following a django video tutorial to build a blog app. I am currently working in the view.py folder and creating the comment section. I followed every step carefully but i got an error while running the code. i will drop the code i wrote i wrote below and the error i'm recieving

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Post
from .forms import CommentForm

def frontend(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/frontend.html', {'posts': posts})
 
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()

            return redirect('post_detail', slug=post.slug)
        else:
            form = CommentForm

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
```

[image: screenshot of the webpage]

I tried changing the if statement to a get, but i am not getting the django form as expected

Comment: ```else:
            form = CommentForm``` this else is wrong its for `request.method` if not `is_valid` indent back will fix you